# Impossible to use pyttsx3: No module named 'pywintypes', but pywin32 is installed

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pywin

I try to use speech synthesis in Python 3.9.13 [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)].
If I understand well, `pyttxs3` is the dedicated module (thank you in advance for any possible alternative!), which I installed successfully:

```
c:\>pip install -U pyttsx3
Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in c:\users\...\python39\site-packages (2.90)
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in c:\users\...\python39\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (1.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\...\python39\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (304)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\...\python39\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (223)
```

but I cannot initialize the engine:  when I do

```
>>> e = pyttsx3.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Program Files\...\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
 File "C:\Users\...\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\...\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
```

I noticed that part of the scripts are in my `Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation...` and some are in `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation...`. I wonder whether that might be the reason for the errors.

How could I fix this? (I also found that there are other modules, `speech` and `pyttsx`, which however appear to be for Python 2.7: they produce `Syntax error: print "..." - did you mean print("...")?` Is there a Python 3 version of `speech` or any other alternative?)

Comment: pyttxs3 is a little (actually very) glitched for example after i removed a part of my code which involved speaking something it still spoke my old code i removed the whole pyttxs3 from my code it still didn't work at last i had to uninstall the package. I can give you an alternative if you want

Comment: Your label should be text to speech not speech to text

Answer (score 1):

pyttxs3 is a little (actually very) glitched for example after i removed a part of my code which involved speaking something it still spoke my old code i removed the whole pyttxs3 from my code it still didn't work at last i had to uninstall the package. I used this function. You need to install **pygame** (it is a game making package but we will use it) and **gtts** i.e google text to speech

```
import os
from pygame import *
from gtts import *

def speak(text: str):
    try:
        tts_ = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
        ran = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        audio_file = 'audio-' + str(ran) + '.mp3'
        tts_.save(audio_file)


        # Starting the mixer
        mixer.init()

        # Loading the song
        mixer.music.load("C:///Users/roopa/PycharmProjects/pokemon game/" + audio_file)

        # Start playing the song
        mixer.music.play()
        clock = time.Clock()
        # infinite loop
        while mixer.music.get_busy():
            clock.tick(60)
            
        mixer.music.unload()
        os.remove(audio_file)

    except gTTSError:
        print('unknown error')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your `pygame` solution didn't work for me (`"Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll"`), but I made it work more simply using `playsound.playsound(audio_file)`. I hope I find a solution avoiding the temp files (maybe with `gTTS.stream...`?), but better than nothing! Thanks again!

Comment: @Max maybe mixer.music.load can only load .mp3 or .wav file. So you might have to save in one of the file format

Answer (score 0):

Roop's answer didn't work out completely for me due to an error `"Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll"`, but it enabled me to find the following working solution:

```
import gtts         # text to mp3 file
import random       # for random file name generation
import playsound    # to play mp3 file
import os           # to remove audio file

def say(text: str, block = True, lang = 'en'):
    """Text-to-speech synthesis using google TTS. If block=True,
        waits until the text is spoken. If False, return a cleanup
        function to delete the temporary audio file."""
    audio_file = f'audio-{random.randint(0, 1000000)}.mp3'
    gtts.gTTS(text, lang = lang).save(audio_file)
    playsound.playsound(audio_file, block = block)
    if block:
        os.remove(audio_file)
    else:
        print(f"Playing sound, don't forget to do: os.remove('{audio_file}')"
              "\n(You can do so by calling the returned function.)")
        return(lambda: os.remove(audio_file)) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    cleanup = say("Good morning, Max!")
    if cleanup: # if block = True, function returns None
        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        cleanup()
```

(It appears to be a [known bug of `playsound`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838123/how-to-make-playsound-not-cut-the-end-of-mp3-file) that the sound isn't played to the end if the script ends too early, therefore I added the sleep(10), but obviously you can do other stuff instead.)

That said, the question regarding `pyttsx3` and `pywin32` remains open.

Comment: I also found this module actually but I needed a way to stop it from speaking in testing of module because else it would speak whole big lines wasting my team, hence used pygame

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/community/77058/while-using-pyttsx-having-following-error-installed-pypiwin32 he has asked for the same problem in pyttsx3 here maybe you can get your answers.

Comment: also according to this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-text-to-speech-by-using-pyttsx3/ you will need to additionally install pypiwin32

Comment: Please note that I showed right at the beginning of my question that `pypiwin32` and other dependencies are installed and up-to-date! (But maybe they have known bugs or installation caveats.)

Comment: Well maybe you can try installing pywintypes (sorry I didn't see the part you told about instaling pypiwin32) You can also try installing pywintypes by pycharm going into settings and adding this package. Also try if import pypiwin32 is working

Comment: google `pywintypes` => *"`pywintypes` is part of the Python for Windows extensions, otherwise known as `pywin32`. You'll need to install that to get access to `pywintypes`."*: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes#18907911

Comment: Sorry no option than